# Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

While passing a storelist from C# code to a SQL query, I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int.

Please help me to resolve this.

```
declare @STORENUM Varchar(100)
set @STORENUM = '1,2'
print @STORENUM

SELECT DISTINCT 
    STORE_NUM, 
    ISNULL(LINE_1_ADDR, '') AS LINE_1_ADDR, 
    ISNULL(LINE_2_ADDR, '') AS LINE_2_ADDR, 
    ISNULL(LINE_3_ADDR, '') AS LINE_3_ADDR,
    CITY_NM, STATE_CD 
FROM 
    Store 
WHERE 
    STORE_NUM IN (CAST(@STORENUM AS INT))
```

Comment: Error info is pretty clear u'r trying to bind varchar to int. U had to conver it first.

Comment: I tried it    --> (cast(@STORENUM as int))

Comment: But you cant convert value with "," to int. How it should be done then?

Comment: I need to get the store details from Store table. For this i'm passing comma separated storelist from my C# code to this query. 

Is there a way to restrict the single quotes instead ?? If I pass 1,2 instead of '1,2' I'm getting the expected result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @STORENUM Varchar(100) , @xml xml

set @STORENUM = '1,2'
set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@STORENUM ,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'


SELECT DISTINCT 
    STORE_NUM, 
    ISNULL(LINE_1_ADDR, '') AS LINE_1_ADDR, 
    ISNULL(LINE_2_ADDR, '') AS LINE_2_ADDR, 
    ISNULL(LINE_3_ADDR, '') AS LINE_3_ADDR,
    CITY_NM, STATE_CD 
FROM 
    Store 
WHERE 
    STORE_NUM IN (
                  select r.value('.','varchar(max)') numbers 
                  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)
                  )
```

Comment: This helped me.. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

The string `'1,2'` is not an integer.  You cannot use `IN` on it.

You have two choices.  Stuff the value into the string.  SQL doesn't support parameters for `IN` lists.

Or, use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE ',' + @STORENUMS + ',' LIKE '%,' + @CAST(STORE_NUM as VARCHAR(255)) + ',%'
```

Comment: This didn't gave me neither an error nor my expected result

Comment: Is there a way to remove the single quotes ? If there are no single quotes in @STORENUM variable, i'm getting the result

Comment: @user1155576 . . . I put the arguments to the `LIKE` in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to do this that way:

1. You had to split your varchar.
   [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)
2. Then you can use IN on (select * from table)

Comment: Exists would be better than IN if you use this pattern you allude to.  Because if a NULL is possible in the SELECT * FROM table... you will not get the results you want.  But if you are going to split the string you can also simple join the tables as well

Comment: Since he declare this value I assume that tables will have expected output.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the single quotes ? If there are no single quotes in @STORENUM variable, i'm getting the result

Comment: I tried this. but it didn't work. I got the same error.

I'm not sure how my storelist is having single qoutes

Comment: Are you sure you do it like : Replace(@STORENUM,'''',''). I got '''' there, not '''. Just do this replace and then select * from @Storenum and show your output.

Comment: Replace gave me 1,2. But in my where clause is this way -- WHERE STORE_NUM in (@STORENUM). This is giving me the same error.

Comment: WHERE STORE_NUM in (1,2) --> Works 
But WHERE STORE_NUM in ('1,2')  --> Gives me an error

Comment: Cause even when u do this variable will always be treat with '' in query. I recomend you to do as i said in first post. U had to split string, then insert it into table and then select this from table in main query and it will work correctly.